# Page not redirecting after PHP contact form submission

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a contact form that sends an email. I have a simple version on the home page that works and redirects to a thank you page. When I try and run the same PHP script on the contact page it sends the form but does not redirect to the thank you page.

**The index.html which send the email and redirects:**

```html
<section class="appointment-one" id="booking">
    <div class="container wow fadeInUp"  data-wow-duration="1.5s">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <h3 class="appointment-one__title" >Book a meeting</h3><!-- /.appointment-one__title -->
            <p class="appointment-one__text">Book a free consultation with one of our experts...</p>
            <!-- /.appointment-one__text -->
            <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" class="appointment-one__form row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="miyami_input" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="email" class="miyami_input" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <select name="discussion" class="selectpicker">
                        <option value="">Discussion about</option>
                        <option value="General">General</option>
                        <option value="IT Solutions">IT Solutions</option>
                        <option value="IT Staffing">IT Staffing</option>
                        <option value="IT Outsourcing">IT Outsourcing</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="appointment-one__bottom">
                        <div class="form_button">
                            <button value="Book a meeting" class="miyami_btn g_bg" type="submit">Book a meeting</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.appointment-one__bottom -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </form><!-- /.appointment-one__form -->
        </div><!-- /.inner-container -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</section><!-- /.appointment-one -->
```

**the sendmail.php file**

```js
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'info@vitosolutions.co.za';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subjects = $_POST['subjects'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$discussion = $_POST['discussion'];
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Email from VITO";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name".
    "\n Discussion: $discussion".
    "\n subject: $subjects \n ".
    "Email: $email_address\n Message: $message";
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    $mail_status = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            //   alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location.href = 'thankyou.html';
        </script>
        <?php
     }else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@vitosolutions.co.za');
            window.location.href = 'contact.html';
        </script>
    <?php }
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: thankyou.html');
}
?>
```

But when I submit the form on the contact page it doesn't redirect.

**The contact.html page which does not redirect**

```html
<div class="contact-info-one__content">
    <div class="container contact-one">
        <div class="block-title text-center">
            <h2 class="block-title__title text-white">Get in touch</h2><!-- /.block-title__title -->
            <p class="block-title__text">Let us help you with your IT requirements.
            </p><!-- /.block-title__text -->
        </div><!-- /.block-title -->
        <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form-vaidated contact-one__form row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" class="miyami_input" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="email" class="miyami_input" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <input type="text" class="miyami_input" placeholder="Subject" name="subjects" required>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <textarea class="miyami_textarea" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div class="form_button">
                    <button value="Send" class="thm-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </form>

    </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.contact-info-one__content -->
```

Before submitting the form - should be redirected
[image: Before submitting the form - should be redirected]

After submitting the form it just clears and doesn't redirect
[image: After submitting the form it just clears and doesn't redirect]

The call to sendmail.php and response
[image: The call to sendmail.php and response]

Comment: Stick to using `header('Location: ......');` to redirect. the javascript parts are being sent to the browser so the actual `header()` call will not work and you should be getting `headers already sent` errors

Comment: PS: `language="javascript"` was deprecated a Long time ago

Comment: I have tried playing around with the redirects adding the if($mail_status){...} I am stuck which the page not redirecting to the thank you page after the form submission

Comment: I have removed the javascript parts. It still only redirects when submitting from the index.html page and not when submitting from the contact.html page

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'info@vitosolutions.co.za';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subjects = $_POST['subjects'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$discussion = $_POST['discussion'];
if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",$email_address)) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if(empty($errors)) {
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Email from VITO";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name".
    "\n Discussion: $discussion".
    "\n subject: $subjects \n ".
    "Email: $email_address\n Message: $message";
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    $mail_status = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            //   alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location.href = 'thankyou.html';
        </script>
        <?php
    }else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@vitosolutions.co.za');
            window.location.href = 'contact.html';
        </script>
    <?php }
}
else {
    ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Errors: <?php echo $errors;?>');
        </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what have you changed, and why?

Answer (score -2):

I always include a redirect status code with the location header. I haven't tried without it, but I know that it does work with it.

```
// status depends on http protocol
if(!$status) {
    $status = strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'1.1') ? 303 : 302;
}
// set redirect headers
http_response_code($status);
header("Location: $to");
```

Any output sent before the redirect will prevent cause `header()` to fail, so you may want to check first with `headers_sent()`. This has always been the cause of redirect issues for me in the past.

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that adding a proper response code makes any difference?

Comment: [The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to. It only provides a meaning when served with a 3xx (redirection) or 201 (created) status response.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location)

Comment: But... I did some digging and it looks like php will look for the Location header and automatically send a 302 status code. This was new information to me.